# Live audio streaming with Android 2.x

Tags: android

I need to play a live stream on devices with 2.x and greater versions. [This](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html) states that it's impossible to play live streams on devices with Android 2.x.

What're my options here ? Especially I'm interested in streaming audio - what format should i pick and in conjunction with which protocol ?

P.S. I've tried Vitamio - don't want to make customers download third party libraries.

**UPD**

- How come I can play this stream "http://188.138.112.71:9018/" ?

Comment: it states https(secure) connection for live streaming is not supported below 3.0 you can stream live video in an http connection using rtp like protocols

Comment: can you give me an example of such stream ? P.S. "HTTP/HTTPS live streaming draft protocol: Not supported before Android 3.0"

Comment: try RTP (or you can even implement a java script enabled web view to accomplish live streaming .. SHORTCUT!)

Comment: give an example of such so I can try

Comment: @midnight did you get any solution. I am sticker. As I have used vitamio library and tootle play store rejected my app because of this library.

Answer (score 3):

try this example for RTSP streaming (the url should support RTSP) for video change the code to support just audio

```
public class MultimediaActivity extends Activity {
private static final String RTSP = "rtsp://url here";

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.multimedia);


         //***VideoView to video element inside Multimedia.xml file
  VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video);
  Log.v("Video", "***Video to Play:: " + RTSP);
  MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
  mc.setAnchorView(videoView);
  Uri video = Uri.parse(RTSP);
  videoView.setMediaController(mc);
  videoView.setVideoURI(video);
  videoView.start();

}
}
```

EDIT:

Live Audio streaming using MediaPlayer in Android
Live Audio streaming in android, from 1.6 sdk onwards is become so easy. In setDataSource() API directly pass the url and audio will play without any issues.

The complete code snippet is,

```
 public class AudioStream extends Activity {

 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
String url = "http://www.songblasts.com/songs/hindi/t/three-idiots/01-Aal_Izz_Well-(SongsBlasts.Com).mp3";
 MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
try {
 mp.setDataSource(url);
 mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
 mp.prepare();
 mp.start();
} catch (Exception e) {
 Log.i("Exception", "Exception in streaming mediaplayer e = " + e);
}
}
}
```

Comment: rtsp://live.media.rai.it/broadcast/radiodue.rm - "this video cannot be played"

Comment: what is the error? ( i had successfully ran this code earlier)

Comment: yep, I've tried it with vlc player. Do you know any mp3 rtsp stream ? And maybe you could link some specifications for implementing mp3 rtsp stream ? Thanks

Comment: check this url and pls remember it wont work on emulator rtsp://v6.cache1.c.youtube.com/CjYLENy73wIaLQnF4qJzpSt4nhMYESARFEIJbXYtZ29vZ2xlSARSBXdhdGNoYMDFmvL1wMysTQw=/0/0/0/video.3gp
and dont forget to add permission internet

Comment: I tested it on samsung i9001. the problem is, I guess, with the file extension. Anyway, I need an audio stream: mp3, aac, whatever might work - do you know any ? I could implement my own but I need a good reference. The application I'm trying to implement is going to be a radio player, since radio couldn't be played with plain http I'm searching for a solution

Comment: i have never tried an audio the situation never arise if i come across any ll surely inform u

Comment: http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2011/06/streaming-radio-stations-on-android.html
http://blog.infidian.com/2008/04/04/tutorial-custom-media-streaming-for-androids-mediaplayer/
check these

Comment: I've seen the second one - many have stated it's not stable solution, besides progressive != live. Thanks for the first one - maybe it's an alternative to rtsp. P.S 01-Aal_Izz_Well-(SongsBlasts.Com).mp3 it's  progressive streaming I guess. The point is to play a radio stream(live).

Answer (score 0):

You can use RTSP protocol which is supported by Android native media player.

```
                    player = new MediaPlayer();
                    player.reset();
                    player.setDataSource(intent.getStringExtra("Path"));
                    player.prepare();
                    player.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

                        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                            player.start();
                        }
                    });
```

Where path would be your rtsp audio streaming url.

Comment: I'm almost convinced to do this way. I need a working rtsp stream to check that it's actually working and a good reference on implementing my own rtsp stream. Thanks

Comment: Google that, sure you will find some good link for that. I recently work on the same but i cant disclose that link. This code works perfectly in my application.

Comment: I found one http://www.pocketjourney.com/audio.mp3 try this might be its working.

Comment: ohh Yes sorry this is not a rtsp URL. you can search rtsp url on wowza.

Comment: rtsp://masds03.htc.com.tw/Bird_On_Aware_QCIF_5fps_mpeg4_23k_amr-nb_12k.mp4 This is live streaming for video i didn't found any audio url yet