# Android Play Audio Continuously

Tags: android, audio

I want to play one Audio file continuously that is being downloaded. Please note that there is no file of fixed size being sent from other side. It's like data is being send from one side and on the other side data is being received. I just want to make this data keep on playing (audio) until no further data is available.

Any suggestions on how to play audio data that is being sent continuously as soon as you start receiving it?

Comment: How is this data being "sent"? Via an RTSP server?

Comment: That part is black box. We have API calls for receiving data.

Comment: did you try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12140801/live-audio-streaming-with-android-2-x

Comment: Then, when you ask whoever supplied you this "API" how you are supposed to use this "data", what did they tell you?